# When is a binary operation bipotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, definition

I learnt that $\max(-,-)$ is a *bipotent binary operation* but **I'm not able to find a definition of *bipotent operation***.

> **QUESTION** A binary operation $*:M\times M \rightarrow M$ is bipotent if
>
> - $a*b \in \{a,b\}$
>
> or when
>
> - $a*b \in S$ with $S \subset M$ and $|S|=2$ ?

*I need references too.*

---

The user Arthur commented with "*The last attempt at a definition makes little sense. Any potential result of $a∗b$ is in some two-element set.*"

I didn't even understood arthur's comment. Sorry.. anyways lets take for example the operation $$a∗b:=c⋅max(a,b)$$ or $$a∘b:=t+max(a,b)$$ in both cases we have that the result belongs to a special $2$-element set: $\{ca,cb\}$ and $\{a+t,b+t\}$... I wonder if those operations $∗$ and $∘$ are bipotent is some sense

Comment: Isn't this a definition?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @nomen I forgot the question mark

Comment: The last attempt at a definition makes little sense. _Any_ potential result of $a*b$ is in some two-element set. Going by the name bipotent, the first bullet point sounds like a good guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5729.pdf) (and in other papers) one finds the definition that a semiring is called *bipotent* if $x+y \in \{x,y\}$ for all elements $x,y$. This definition only uses the binary operation $+$. Therefore, I *think* that this is also a general definition of bipotent binary operations. See also "Tropical and Idempotent Mathematics and Applications", p. 128. A typical example is the [tropical semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_semiring). On the other hand, googling "bipotent operation" gives only this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848564/when-is-a-binary-operation-bipotent) result.

Comment: Ye! I learnt about Bipotent semiring because of that example (the tropical semirings $\Bbb T_{max}$ and $\Bbb T_{min}$)

Meanwhile I found other text too (again about tropical and idempotent mathematics) and I still found the definition you gave me..
So *I think* that if I have to give a name to the property $a*b \in S$ with $S \subset M$ and $|S|=2$ I can't use Bipotent but maybe I should introduce some new term like *"generalized bipotent"* operation or something like that.

Comment: As explained by Arthur, this property (with $M$) is empty.

Comment: Ah, I'm rly stupid...I didn't even understood arthur's comment. Sorry.. anyways lets take for example the operation $a*b:=c\cdot max(a,b)$ or $a\circ b:=t+max(a,b)$ in both cases we have that the result belongs to a special 2 element set: $\{ca,cb\}$ and $\{a+t,b+t\}$... I wonder if those operations $*$ and $\circ$ are bipotent is some sense..

Comment: I hope that this can make more sense than the second point in my question.